# Launch urls based on different versions of java

Tags: java, url, cross-browser, launcher

I am in a situation where i need to create a simple launcher that allows me too select which web address to launch with different versions of java.  I have researched several sites.  Having the user change windows settings is not an option as it would generate too many support calls or user does not have priviliges. What i want is a programming way to set or change the version of java being used to launch a url.  I have seen proprietary systems make launchers with a gui that allows you to change address and java version and then launch it in a browser.  I am new to development and obviously having trouble understanding which techniques to use.

Will you please point me in the right direction.  I am comfortable writing guis(in c# or java) I just need to know how to write the function for the launch button?

```
function launchbutton(url, javaversion)

{

If (javaversionselect == 1.3)
{
open url in default browser running java version 1.3
}

If (javaversionselect == 1.4)
{
open url in default browser running java version 1.4
}

If (javaversionselect == 1.5)
{
open url in default browser running java version 1.5
}

If (javaversionselect == 1.6)
{
open url in default browser running java version 1.6}
}
```

Comment: You want to programatically open a url in the "default" browser and select which JVM is used by the browser for the purpose of hosting applets?  I am fairly sure nothing like that is possible.

Comment: Is using a custom browser a possibility? You could possibly do this with varying versions of 'Portable Java' and some swap magic.

Comment: @KirkWoll  I may not be describing this accurately but i have seen a program where you select a url then select the java version and click on launch.  If you were to go to the address manually it would not load the page unless you had the right version of java on your system.  Is there any other ways this might be done?

Comment: @VaughanHits  Could you elaborate more or link to an article please?

Answer (score 0):

Bare Bones Browser Launcher will detect the java version and use the appropriate calls.

http://www.centerkey.com/java/browser/

Answer (score 0):

You wan't be able to change the version of java that for example 'IE' or 'Chrome' use from withing your  application, your only solutions would be to use some kind of embedded browser

- jBrowser
- XPCOM from Mozilla
- Browse source and look on how Eclipse embedded their browser

Answer (score 0):

You can write an applet that does it.  Compile something like this, using `javac -target 1.3`:

```
public class Redirector
extends Applet {
    @Override
    public void start() {
        String newURL;

        Package pkg = Object.class.getPackage();
        if (pkg.isCompatibleWith("1.7")) {
            newURL = "java17.html";
        } else if (pkg.isCompatibleWith("1.6")) {
            newURL = "java16.html";
        } else if (pkg.isCompatibleWith("1.5")) {
            newURL = "java15.html";
        } else if (pkg.isCompatibleWith("1.4")) {
            newURL = "java14.html";
        } else {
            newURL = "java13.html";
        }

        try {
            getAppletContext().showDocument(new URL(newURL));
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            showStatus(e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

If you really want let the user choose the Java version for himself, you can create UI elements in your applet for that:

```
public class Redirector
extends Applet
implements ActionListener {
    private Choice list;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        try {
            EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    list = new Choice();
                    list.add("1.7");
                    list.add("1.6");
                    list.add("1.5");
                    list.add("1.4");
                    list.add("1.3");

                    Button button = new Button("Launch");
                    button.addAtionListener(Redirector.this);

                    add(new Label("Java version:"));
                    add(list);
                    add(button);
                }
            });
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void actionPeformed(ActionEvent event) {
        String newURL;
        String version = list.getSelectedItem();
        if (version.equals("1.7")) {
            newURL = "java17.html";
        } else if (version.equals("1.6")) {
            newURL = "java16.html";
        } else if (version.equals("1.5")) {
            newURL = "java15.html";
        } else if (version.equals("1.4")) {
            newURL = "java14.html";
        } else {
            newURL = "java13.html";
        }

        try {
            getAppletContext().showDocument(new URL(newURL));
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            showStatus(e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```